# Successively collapse array till it contains alternative positive and negative values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

The problem is here to add all the adjacent numbers of array if they have same sign. So I ran a loop over it using if loop initially. The code is as follows:

```
a=[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]*a[i+1] >= 0:
        a[i]=a[i]+a[i+1]
        a.pop(i+1)
print(a)
```

It showed me index out of range error. I presumed it was due to the length of list getting updated due to pop at the end and hence the index could be out of range. Hence, I tried with while loop as follows:

```
a=[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
lena,i= len(a),0
while i <= lena:
    if a[i]*a[i+1] >= 0:
        a[i]=a[i]+a[i+1]
        a.pop(i+1)
        lena=len(a)
    i=+1
print(a)
```

Here, the loop takes too much time and I had to manually stop the program. I believe it runs into infinite loop. I don't understand what is happening.
My pseudo code is simple, if the product of i and i=1 is >=0, replace i element with i + (i+1) elements and then pop out the i+1 elements.
Kindly clarify the mistakes and make the code work. If there are any better methods that probably use slicing of lists or any other methods please let me know of those too.

Solution:
Just tweak around with indexes and was able to get this.

```
a=[-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
lena,i= len(a)-1,1
while i <= lena:
    if a[i]*a[i-1] >= 0:
        a[i-1]=a[i]+a[i-1]
        a.pop(i)
        i-=1
        lena=len(a)-1
    i+=1
print(a)
```

This works as of now. Kindly let me know if there are examples where it breaks down.

Comment: If you print values of `i` and `lena`, shouldn't you then know what's happening?

Comment: ops! updated =+ to += but it still shows out of index error. I added the print(i,lena) and i goes from 1 to 7 and lena is 9 for first 5 times and then 8 2 times. I think the error is just because of last iteration. How do I resolve that?

Comment: What happens if you have 3 adjacent numbers with the same sign? Are they all supposed to be added together and only one number with that sign should remain?

Comment: Your index error can be fixed if you run the while loop with condition i<lena-1 instead of i<=lena, but the question is if the output you get in that case is what you want

Comment: @Jako Yes if there are more than one number of similar sign all should add up. The end result should be a list with alternative signs. It's basically a part of problem I came across on leetcode. 
https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/

Comment: There are different methods for this as shown in the post. 
https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/discuss/1595195/C%2B%2BPython-7-Simple-Solutions-w-Explanation-or-Brute-Force-%2B-DP-%2B-Kadane-%2B-Divide-and-Conquer

However, I tried it myself and came up with an algorithm as discussed in the post.
https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/discuss/2080276/53.-Maximum-Subarray
Hope this makes sense of the problem and clears a few things up. I plan to further do this as a function by def so I can recursively call it till it exhausts but with fixed slice widths of 3 later on.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of doing this in place and getting problems with iterating over the list you are changing, why not create a new list and working with that one instead? Like so:

```
a = [-2,1,3,4,-1,2,1,-5,-4]
b = [a[0]]
j = 0
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    if (b[j]<0 and a[i]<0) or (b[j]>0 and a[i]>0):
        b[j]+=a[i]
    else:
        b.append(a[i])
        j+=1
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[-2,8,-1,3,-9]
```

Also, this solution has no problems with index errors since we never try to access two indicies of a list at once.

Comment: Yes this would be best and easy but I was working on a challenge, the less time and space complexity it has the better it is and so I tried copying it in place. Otherwise it will consume double memory and possibly more in subsequent operations. This would not matter much in small arrays but mess up horribly if I have a dataset of large numbers, say landsat satellite data of measurement errors sent each second and for a month or so the data will be huge.